# passing `this` to a constructor from different fragments

Tags: java, android-fragments, constructor, android-arrayadapter

I have four different fragment classes that all instantiate an instance of my custom ArrayAdapter.  They all need to include a reference to themselves in the ArrayAdapter's constructor.

My four fragment classes are "FeaturedFragment", "GeneralInfoFragment", "VisitingFragment" and "LivingHereFragment".

In order to accept references to each of these different classes, I currently have four constructors in my ArrayAdapter class :

```
infoViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MordorInfo> list, FeaturedFragment cb) {
    super (context, 0, list);
    myContext = context;
    infoList = list;
    featuredCallback = cb;
}

infoViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MordorInfo> list, GeneralInfoFragment cb) {
    super (context, 0, list);
    myContext = context;
    infoList = list;
    generalInfoCallback = cb;
}

infoViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MordorInfo> list, LivingHereFragment cb) {
    super (context, 0, list);
    myContext = context;
    infoList = list;
    livingHereCallback = cb;
}

infoViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MordorInfo> list, VisitingFragment cb) {
    super (context, 0, list);
    myContext = context;
    infoList = list;
    visitingCallback = cb;
}
```

Is there someway to combine these into a single constructor?  Perhaps by accepting a somewhat generic type in the constructor for the 'this' parameter?  Or maybe have all four fragments extend the same class so I can cast `this` when calling the constructor?

Once I have the references, I use them to execute a public method in the appropriate fragment :

```
if (featuredCallback != null) {
    featuredCallback.setButtonCallback(currentInfo.gotoRef);
} else if (generalInfoCallback != null) {
    generalInfoCallback.setButtonCallback(currentInfo.gotoRef);
} else if (visitingCallback != null) {
    visitingCallback.setButtonCallback(currentInfo.gotoRef);
} else if (livingHereCallback != null) {
    livingHereCallback.setButtonCallback(currentInfo.gotoRef);
}
```

I'd like to make that call from a single class reference variable.

Comment: Is FeaturedFragment, GeneralInfoFragment etc implements/ extends class has common interface/ class

Comment: They all extend Fragment and implement View.OnClickListener.  And they all have `public setButtonCallback(int position)` which is the method that the ArrayAdapter uses the fragment reference to call.

Comment: I guess all four fragments could instantiate a new class `ManageButtons` that implements `setButtonCallBack()`.  The fragments could pass the TextViews that need to be updated to `ManageButtons` in its constructor, and then pass their reference to `ManageButtons` in to the ArrayAdapter constructor instead of each unique fragment reference?  A little more complex to setup, but not too bad.

Comment: Is `setButtonCallback(int position)` method present on `Fragment` or `View.OnClickListener` ? If yes which one?

Comment: It is not present in either, I currently duplicate its implementation in each of my four fragment classes.

Comment: Actually, with a little work, I could probably collapse the four fragment classes into a single class, they do a lot of the same things.

Comment: I have posted an answer please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you're doing it wrong. You're even not asking me in previous question. You do not need to define concrete callback type in your adapter, just declare it as `CallbackInterface callback` then pass a concrete implementation to it:

```
InfoViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MordorInfo> list, CallbackInterface cb) {
    super (context, 0, list);
    myContext = context;
    infoList = list;
    callback = cb;
}
```

If you want to create a `InfoViewAdapter` with `GeneralInfoFragment` callback, you just invoke:

```
GeneralInfoFragment callback = new GeneralInfoFragment();
new InfoViewAdapter(context, list, callback);
```

By define common callback method in your `CallbackInterface`, you can invoke them without knowledge about the concrete implementation class (which called late-binding or polymorph):

```
callback.execute();
```

Comment: So, `CallbackInterface` is a new class which I define, that implements a public method or interface for `execute()`?  Then the four fragments can instantiate `CallbackInterface` and pass that reference to `CustomAdapter` for it to use to access `execute`?

Comment: Correct. You do not need to create `InfoViewAdapter` with 4 constructor like that, because it only differ in `callback` instance. You just pass the callback to that like I write above.

Comment: Ok, I will play with that, it sounds like what I tried to explain in my question comment above.  I'm trying to implement this when a lot of the concepts involved, we haven't really touched on yet in my Android class.  Thank you for the great information.